# Default value on parent destructured

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a variable named `state`. Initially this is an empty object:

```
var state = {}
```

At some time later I get a value of `map:{lat:0,lng:0}` in there:

```
var state = { map:{lat:0,lng:0} };
```

I needed to destructure out `lat` and `lng` in a fool proof way, so I was trying to set map to a default value of an empty object.

I tried this:

```
var { map={}:{lat,lng} } = state;
```

However this does not work. Is there anyway to set `map` to a default value of empty object before destructuring further on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value comes after the destructuring target:

```js
var state = {};
var { map:{lat,lng}={} } = state;
console.log(lat, lng);
```